# Removing all characters after a white space?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I would like to remove all characters after the first white space instance.

My use case:
In my table, I have a name column that is not separated into first and last. They are combined (e.g. 'John Doe' in one cell). I would like to delete everything after the first whitespace instance (e.g. 'John Doe' --> 'John').

Is that possible in AMPScript?

I saw the trim() function, but that does not seem to do what I want.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is a combination of [IndexOf](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/IndexOf.htm) and [SubString](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/Substring.htm).

You would use IndexOf to find the first whitespace and then use substring to pull from first character up to the index of the whitespace.

Example:

```
%%[

    SET @Name = "John Doe"

    SET @Index = IndexOf(@Name, " ")

    SET @fName = SubString(@Name, 1, Subtract(@Index, 1))

]%%
```

**You subtract 1 from the index because the index includes the count of the white space character.

Keep in mind if the person has a two name first name, it will cut off the second part. E.g. "Jean Marie Jones" would just become "Jean" instead of "Jean Marie".